# I need to loop through all input elements

Tags: jquery, loops, dynamic, input, each

I am trying to loop through all dynamically created inputs inside a div element. The first input element already exists in the dom.

I have used the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#myClickLink",function(){
   $("#divElement input").each(function(){ 
      alert($(this).val()); 
   });  
});
```

The problem is that I am only getting the first input element, any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your `HTML` also, or make an `online demo` like on `Fiddle`.

Comment: `input[type=text]` try this instead..

Comment: My problem was in my dynamic generated inputs, I was appendTo another div... thank you so much for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append) `input element first,` then only you can get the `newly created input elements` in `$.each loop` like,

```
$(document).on("click", "#myClickLink",function(){
   newid=$("#divElement input").length+1;
   // append a new input first
   $("#divElement").append('<input type="text" id="'+newid+'" value ="'+newid+'" />');
   $("#divElement input").each(function(){ 
      alert($(this).val()); 
   });  
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PUe6u/) and [Demo with add more and check links](http://jsfiddle.net/PUe6u/1/)

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me find my mistake, I was using appendTo and pointing to another div

Answer (score 0):

your code works when its wrapped in a jquery ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#myClickLink",function(){
        $("#divElement input").each(function(){ 
            alert($(this).val()); 
        });  
    });
});
```

Comment: how can you know that without knowing his html markup?

Comment: He is `only getting the first input element`, so his code is working

Comment: I tested it with my own code using the all the elements he provided in his code.

Comment: I got my problem solved, thank you anyways for all of your help.